# SQL Server throwing "could not serialize" based on join order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-optimization

I'm seeing something I've never seen before in SQL Server. I'm getting an error message about a character (vertical tab) that is not allowed based (seemingly) only on join order. Note that I cannot find the character anywhere in the actual data.

Has anyone else seen this? Thanks in advance! Errors and code below:

This query fails:

```
SELECT 
    'prefix-' + COALESCE(CAST(a.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)), CAST(cta.id AS VARCHAR(MAX))) AS [object_id],
    objectValues.Value AS related_values
FROM 
    object_table a
CROSS APPLY 
    dbo.tvfGetValuesCsvForObject(a.id) AS objectValues
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    v_object_table_change_tracking_aggregation cta ON a.id = cta.id
WHERE 
    'object-' + COALESCE(CAST(a.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)), CAST(cta.id AS VARCHAR(MAX))) = 'object-123456'
```

The error message:

> Msg 6841, Level 16, State 1, Line 111
>   FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'NoName' because it contains a character (0x000B) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.

This code succeeds:

```
SELECT 
    'prefix-' + COALESCE(CAST(a.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)), CAST(cta.id AS VARCHAR(MAX))) AS [object_id],
    objectValues.Value AS related_values
FROM 
    object_table a
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    v_object_table_change_tracking_aggregation cta ON a.id = cta.id
CROSS APPLY 
    dbo.tvfGetValuesCsvForObject(a.id) AS objectValues
WHERE 
    'object-' + COALESCE(CAST(a.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)), CAST(cta.id AS VARCHAR(MAX))) = 'object-123456'
```

Note that the only difference between the two is the join/cross apply order, and that the cardinality of the values contained in a.id is the same (because the full outer join will not drop any records).

I've also included the definition of the related table-valued-function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tvfGetEaValuesCsvForProject (@object_id INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
    RETURN
    WITH CSVList AS
    (
        SELECT
        (
            SELECT 
                '"' + REPLACE(kvp.EAValueChar, '"', '') + '", ' ,
                '"' + REPLACE(kvp.EAValueCharMax, '"', '') + '", '
            FROM dbo.object_related_fields_kvp kvp
                JOIN dbo.field_definitions def 
                    ON def.id = kvp.id
            WHERE kvp.object_id = @object_id
                --text, longtext
                AND def.value_type IN (0,8)
            ORDER BY kvp.id 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS Value
    )

    SELECT 
        '[' + 
            --remove trailing comma
            LEFT(Value,LEN(Value) - 1)+ 
        ']' AS Value
    FROM CSVList
GO
```

I don't believe the view is related because it isn't handling the concatenation of the columns, so I haven't included the definition of the view. Also, I stripped out column/table names and replaced them with generic names. I think I kept references intact, but if you see mistakes there, that's why.

Comment: It's a well-known feature of the optimizer that it may evaluate expressions even for rows that are nominally excluded by a `WHERE` or `JOIN` condition. (I use the word "feature" loosely here; it enhances performance but can cause many nasty surprises.) You should therefore check if *any* row in `object_related_fields_kvp` has the offending character in `EAValueChar` or `EAValueCharMax` somewhere. If they flow past the optimizer in a stage of the query where it's evaluating the `FOR XML PATH`, this error will trigger.

Comment: Awesome, you were right! If you don't mind, make this an answer, and I'll give you credit for it. The query I ran is this: 

`select * from object_related_attributes_kvp where ValueCharMax like '%' + char(0x0B) + '%' or ValueChar like '%' + char(0x0B) + '%'`